# Find parent object within Proxy

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

Lets say I have an object `target`, with a tree like shown below, and a Proxy set up that intercepts `.push` on Arrays. How would I intercept `examples.push(1)` at the very last line, do some checks and set `t` to `target`?

I **don't** have access to `target`. I want to access it solely from the Proxy intercepting `examples.push(1)`

Looking for something like this:

```
const target = {
  example: {
    examples: []
  }
};

let t;

const handler = {
  apply(target, thisArg, argumentsList) {
    if (!t) {
      try {
        if (typeof thisArg.parent?.parent === "object") {  // searching for "target"
          const temp = thisArg.parent.parent; // found object, maybe target?

          if (temp.example?.examples) t = temp; // if temp has the correct attributes, found target, set t
        }
      } catch (e) {
        console.error("Error occurred:", e);
      }
    }

    return Reflect.apply(target, thisArg, argumentsList);
  }
};

Array.prototype.push = new Proxy(Array.prototype.push, handler);

target.example.examples.push(1); // gets checked by proxy, and "t" is set to target
```

Comment: No, that is not possible. The `examples` array has no knowledge (accessible to you) which objects have references to it. Note that that same `examples` array could be referenced by many different objects/arrays/variables. This is not related to proxies, as you would have the same issue if you would pass the `examples` array to a function: that function will not be able to find out where you have a reference to that array.

Comment: @trincot, is there any other way I could do this? I've messed with queryObjects before, and then do a `.find`, but that's just a devtools thing.

Comment: That depends what you expect? What if I have `examples = []; b = { example: {examples}}; c = { example: {examples}}`? What should happen when pushing a value unto `examples`?

Comment: @trincot did you mean b = { example: examples }?

Comment: No, that would not be the structure like `target` has. Why do you ask?

Comment: Let me clarify what I'm trying to do (I'm bad at explaining, I'm sorry): I don't have access to `target`, all I want is to find `target` and store it into `t`.

This works in devtools: 

`queryObjects(Object);`
 (store queried objects as temp1)
`t = temp1.find(e=>e?.example?.examples);`

Comment: That is a different question, and seems unrelated to replacing `push`. So you want to find out which objects have the `target` structure? Then why not mandate that these objects are created with your own constructor?

Comment: @trincot 
a. I read your earlier post wrong

b. This script is to be injected, because of this I can't alter creation of `target`, I don't have access to it's creation. All I want to do is access it and store it in a variable.

If you have any other ideas how I could do this, please mention them

Comment: Is this question about replacing `push`? Or is that not an essential part of your question? When do you want to access the target object?

Comment: @trincot 

The reason I mentioned push is because I knew for a fact `target.example.examples` would be pushed to. My initial idea was to filter through all pushes and do some checks to see if the structure of the parent object matched up with what's being pushed.

Comment: Well there is no parent reference (moreover, an object/array can be referenced by many, not necessary just one "parent"). So, no, this is not possible.

Comment: The only handles you have are in the global object, `window`, which will have properties that are aliases for all `var`-declared, global variables. The `window` object properties can be iterated, so you can find objects there. However, variables that have been declared with `let` or `const`, or which are declared as local variables are not accessible. Note that devtools can do more than what JS offers, because it is baked into the host of the JS engine.